# What are the differences between round and square steppers?

Tags: stepper-motor

I have managed to salvage some round and square hybrid steppers, and I have noticed that the square ones seem to be much more powerful motors. Other than shape, what are the general differences? Is one type better than the other performance-wise?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there should be no difference in performance based only on the shape of the steppers; their performance depends on how they are built. IIRC steppers are mostly characterized by their holding torque, however they could also be characterized by other secondary characteristics like number of steps/step size, maximum speed, etc.

A round stepper **could** be a more efficient shape, i.e. have the most efficient mass/materials to magnetic field strength ratio. But a square package is more pragmatic for actually using the stepper.

IMHO, the 'best' (shortcut) evaluation of a stepper is its weight, since heavier steppers have stronger (i.e. heavier) magnets, which should translate into more torque. (by 'shortcut evaluation,' I mean useful when you don't have proper specifications/data sheets for the steppers.)

As far as i know, if one stepper is stronger than another, it's internal design/construction is responsible for the performance more than its shape.

one possible exception are steppers that are constrained by their size, and are designed to have the best torque to size ratio. For example pancake steppers, are designed to be small and compact with, generally, the highest torque possible for their size.

Comment: There's a lot of truth here.  One thing not mentioned is that the same assembly is typically sold with a range of different winding impedances.   For performance (torque at speed) one typically wants the lowest impedance coil configuration offered - depending on what the nameplate does or doesn't mention that might be the lowest voltage or the highest current.

Answer (score 1):

I only deal with fairly small motors.  In general square stepper motors are higher quality, higher resolution motors for precision applications, while small round motors are often used for their low speed torque in applications such as power windows where precision is of much less importance.

Most square motors follow NEMA standards and will offer 100 or more steps per revolution, while round motors are often 40 steps or less.  And as the previous answer mentions the square motors are easier to mount and secure well for consistent behavior, while round motors usually rely on a screw through a pair of external wings on the face plate.